# symbolic links gone after restart/upgrade

Tags: macos, symbolic-link

I can create symlink [(something like that)](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html) and it works. Until next restart.  <strike>How do I force `iterm` to restore symlinks?</strike>  How do I preserve these after a system update?

Comment: You must be very confused.  The symlink is part of the filesystem and has nothing to do with `iterm`.  If your symlinks are going away, it is for another reason.  Where (which folder) are you putting these symlinks?

Comment: I'm putting them in /bin

Comment: might be they were gone after I updated to Mavericks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you stated you just updated to Mavericks… that's the culprit. Doing an OS upgrade (or a reinstall of OS X) will overwrite system directories, `/bin` being one of these.

If you don't want your links changed, it's better to put them somewhere the OS will not overwrite, such as `/usr/local/bin`. You need to add this directory to your `PATH` though.